# Abstracting away any configuration using IConfigurationStore and IWindsorInstaller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, configurationmanager

I have multiple implementations of IWindsorInstallers. In their Install methods I want them to use some predefined values. I hoped to do this using the IConfigurationStore but it's not clear for me how to do this.

I can't seem to find any code examples for this.

My workaround is registering these values as object in the container first, and then resolving them in the installers that need the values. But I don't think this is a very good solution.

Comment: IConfigurationStore is generally used by things like Windsor Facilities, which are very tightly coupled to Castle.Windsor - not typically what you want to do in an app. AppSettings are a good way to provide run-time parameters. I typically do it this way: http://kozmic.net/2014/03/22/strongly-typed-app-settings-with-castle-dictionaryadapter/

Comment: Ok, so I better not try to use the IConfigurationStore. Interesting blog post, but we can't retrieve the values from a static XML file. The values we are trying to make "global" for a composition root are determined by console arguments and other environmental values.

Comment: With command line arguments I would simply do what it sounds like you are doing now: populating an object with the parsed values and then registering that object in the composition root so it accessible to any components that need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract away both the console and environment settings. You can use the suggested article by @PhilDegenhardt. An example may look like this - the console settings come from static class through interface and the environment settings come from method. You can combine/refine and move classes around to avoid bad dependencies around your app to get to the desired behavior :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using Castle.Components.DictionaryAdapter;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Context;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using ConsoleAppStrongTypeConfig;


namespace CastleDictionaryAdapterExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            GetUserSettings();

            var programComponent = ContainerRegistrar.Container.Resolve<IProgramServiceConfigDependent>();

            programComponent.ConfigDependentAction();
            programComponent = ContainerRegistrar.Container.Resolve<IProgramServiceConfigDependent>();
            programComponent.ConfigDependentAction();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void GetUserSettings()
        {
            ContainerRegistrar.SetupContainer();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter setting 1");
            Console.WriteLine();

            string setting1 = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter setting 2");
            Console.WriteLine();

            string setting2 = Console.ReadLine();

            GlobalUserConsoleSettings.consoleSettings = new DictionaryAdapterFactory().GetAdapter<IConsoleSettings>(
                new Hashtable() { 
                { "consoleSetting1", setting1 }, 
                { "consoleSetting2", setting2 } }
                );
        }
    }

    public static class GlobalUserConsoleSettings
    {
        public static IConsoleSettings consoleSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IConsoleSettings
    {
        string consoleSetting1 { get; set; }
        int consoleSetting2 { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEnvironmentSettings
    {
        string environmentSetting1 { get; set; }
        int environmentSetting2 { get; set; }

        long environmentSettingWhichChanges { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IProgramServiceConfigDependent
    {
        void ConfigDependentAction();
    }
    class ProgramServiceConfigDependent : IProgramServiceConfigDependent
    {
        private readonly IConsoleSettings _consoleSettings;
        private readonly IEnvironmentSettings _envSettings;

        public ProgramServiceConfigDependent(IConsoleSettings consoleSettings, IEnvironmentSettings envSettings)
        {
            _consoleSettings = consoleSettings;
            _envSettings = envSettings;
        }

        public void ConfigDependentAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff.");
            Console.WriteLine("Console setting 1 :" + _consoleSettings.consoleSetting1);
            Console.WriteLine("Console setting 2 :" + _consoleSettings.consoleSetting2);
            Console.WriteLine("Environment setting 2 :" + _envSettings.environmentSetting1);
            Console.WriteLine("Environment setting 2 :" + _envSettings.environmentSetting2);
            Console.WriteLine("Environment setting which changes with time :" + _envSettings.environmentSettingWhichChanges);
        }
    }

    public static class ContainerRegistrar
    {
        internal static WindsorContainer Container { get; set; }

        public static void SetupContainer()
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

            container.Register(
               Component.For<IConsoleSettings>().UsingFactoryMethod(GetGlobalUserConsoleSettings),
                Component.For<IEnvironmentSettings>().UsingFactoryMethod(GetLiveEnvironmentSettings).LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<IProgramServiceConfigDependent>().ImplementedBy<ProgramServiceConfigDependent>().LifestyleTransient()
                );

            Container = container;
        }

        private static IConsoleSettings GetGlobalUserConsoleSettings(IKernel k, CreationContext c)
        {
            return GlobalUserConsoleSettings.consoleSettings;
        }

        private static IEnvironmentSettings GetLiveEnvironmentSettings(IKernel k, CreationContext c)
        {
            string envSet1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            int envSet2 = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;

            long envSet3 = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            IEnvironmentSettings envSet = new DictionaryAdapterFactory().GetAdapter<IEnvironmentSettings>(
                new Hashtable() { 
                { "environmentSetting1", envSet1 }, 
                { "environmentSetting2", envSet2 },
                { "environmentSettingWhichChanges", envSet3}}
                );

            return envSet;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://github.com/ognyandim/AzureStrongConfig) is a sample project for Azure/MVC and [another one](https://github.com/ognyandim/StrongTypedConfig) for console app. Both are for strong typed configurations and abstracting away the ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Yes that's more or less what we did, like Phil Degenhardt said.

Comment: Ognyan. Your edit of my question does not represent the idea of my question. Can you please let me pose my own question like I intended it, not as you wrongly understood it?

Comment: Hi, @Gurdt. I do not mind to leave the question as is at all. Because I am under 2000 reputation all of my edits are just "suggestions" and are revised by other more reputable peers before they are applied. Technically - I am not making direct edits of questions. I apologize.

Comment: I found the questions fitting more into the current formulation because it looks so much like it. The mechanisms you use and the goal you try to achieve are generally called configuration abstraction. Although if you want to push "dynamic parameter" inside method there is a good explanatory [docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/passing-arguments.md). If your question is about passing parameters as used in the term "dynamic parameters" I will paste you exemplar code for that.